# Is this ring quadratically closed?

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the ring parametrized by $\{a_i, b_i\}$ of functions $f(t) = \sum_i a_i e^{-b_i t}$.  Is this ring quadratically closed?  If not, how well can I approximate the square root of an element of the ring using another element of the ring?

We can assume complex $a_i, b_i$ where $b_i$'s real component is nonnegative.

Let the ring multiplication of two elements $f_1$, $f_2$ be regular multiplication: $f(t) = f_1(t)f_2(t)$.

Comment: Sorry, I have a question since I don't quite understand your description. What is the ring multiplication? Pointwise? Or convolution?

Comment: @rschwieb Good question; I edited the question.

Comment: Three issues: (absolute?) convergence, domain of convergence, $b_i\in\Bbb{C}$ ? Which makes the question unanswerable.

Comment: @reuns yes, the domain is the complex numbers, and yes absolute convergence.

Comment: Absolute convergence on which domain? If $f$ has a simple zero at $t_0$ then its square root is non analytic there so the putative series for $f^{1/2}$ cannot converge absolutely or locally uniformly on an annulus containing $t_0$.

Comment: @reuns Good point.